# selectOneMenu is not being populated

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to display a new dialog box with a card payment form. It will be displayed (rendered = true) after click on a button. The issue is that the selectOneMenu is not being populated. If I close the dialog and open it again it works. I know that at the beginning the DOM is not detecting the dialog so the methods that populate the menu are not being called. Is there a way to populate the dropdown? I have been trying with AJAX property, updated form, etc.

Code to open the form:

```
<p:panel styleClass="commandButtons">
    <p:commandButton
            id="newCard"
            value="#{msg.global_payWithNewCard}"
            immediate="true"
            action="#{cardPaymentDialogManager.toggleNewCard}"
            rendered="#{!cardPaymentDialogManager.newCard}"
            icon="ui-icon-plus"
            update="@form"/>
</p:panel>
```

Select Menu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu
           id="newCardExpirationMonth"
           value="#{cardPaymentDialogManager.cardPaymentViewModel.expirationMonth}"
           style="width: 107px; margin-right: 10px;">
              <f:selectItem
                itemLabel="#{msg.global_month}"
                noSelectionOption="true" />
              <f:selectItems value="#{cardPaymentDialogManager.expirationMonth}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Post your `cardPaymentDialogManager` class

Comment: Did you update the dialog? The dialog is in the same form? Or it has its own form? In the second case, you must update and the form in the dialog.

Comment: Yeah It is in the same form. The method I'm calling is :     public List<SelectItem> getExpirationYear() {
        return callStaticMehodThatReturnsTheList;
    } and the class is annotated with ViewScoped and
ManagedBean

Comment: Please, [mcve] and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info No one is able to reproduce your problem based on the information provided so far, which even contains relatively a lot of distracting noise. You need to post a normal MCVE snippet based on instructions given in above two links.